# Problema en la inyección de un provider en un config con AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

soy nuevo en el framework de AngularJS y tengo un problema al configurar un `provider` en un `config`. El código es de un manual (lo digo por si no le encontrais sentido funcional).

Estoy usando la versión 1.3.0 de AngularJS (https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/angular.min.js)

Bien, vamos al lío:

1º Declaro mi constante:

```
app.constant("opcionDeHaseo","MD5");
```

2º declaro mi objeto que usaré como `provider`

```
function HashProvider () {
  var _algoritmo="";

  this.setAlgoritmo=function(algoritmo) {
    _algoritmo=algoritmo;
  };

  this.metodo= function (hash){
        return  hash + "haseando mi string"; 
    }

  this.$get=function() {
        var funQueDevolveraMiProvider;

        if (_algoritmo==="MD5") {
            funQueDevolveraMiProvider=metodo;
        } else {//aqui podriamos meter mas tipos de funciones
          throw Error("El tipo de algoritmo no es válido:"+_algoritmo);
        }

        var funQueDevolveraMiProvider=function(message) {
            return hashFunction(message);
        }

        return funQueDevolveraMiProvider;
  }}
```

3º Declaro mi `provider`

```
app.provider("hash",HashProvider);
```

4º Declaro mi `config`

```
app.config(function(hash,opcionDeHaseo) {
hash.setAlgoritmo(opcionDeHaseo);
});
```

**aqui ya cuando ejecuto este codigo falla y me devuelve este error**

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=app&p1=%5B%24injector%3Aunpr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.0%2F%24injector%2Funpr%3Fp0%3Dhash%0Ay%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.3.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A6%3A416%0AJb%2Fq.%24injector%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.3.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A145%0Ad%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.3.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A165%0Ae%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.3.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A36%3A426%0Ad%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.3.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A124%0Ag%2F%3C%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.3.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A256%0Ar%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.3.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A7%3A300%0Ag%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.3.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A35%3A33%0AJb%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.3.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A38%3A269%0Ad%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.3.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A3%0Arc%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.3.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A316%0AEd%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.3.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A130%0A%40https%3A%2F%2Fcode.angularjs.org%2F1.3.0%2Fangular.min.js%3A246%3A98%0Aj%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fcrm%2Fresources%2Fjs%2FjsDefault%2Fjquery-3.2.1.min.js%3A2%3A29997%0Ag%2F%3C%2Fk%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fcrm%2Fresources%2Fjs%2FjsDefault%2Fjquery-3.2.1.min.js%3A2%3A30313%0A

¿Sabeis qué puede ser?, si pongo solo la constante en el `config` no me falla y me devuelve el valor, falla solo cuando meto el provider.

Muchas gracias. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando declaras un provider como:

```
app.provider("hash", HashProvider);
```

Lo que estas disponibilizando es un provider con nombre "hashProvider", como aparece especificado en la [documentación](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.20/docs/api/auto/service/$provide#provider)

> The name of the instance. NOTE: the provider will be available under
>   `name + 'Provider'` key.

Comment: muchisimas gracias!